# Uber not Fetch Product

Tags: ios, swift, uber-api

I want to integrate uber in my iOS Application. But I am unable to fetch Product. I am using carthage for downloading framework. But my response is shown below. Where we set base url sandbox. I am unable to find this.

let loginManager = LoginManager()
            loginManager.login(requestedScopes:[.request,.profile], presentingViewController: self, completion: { accessToken , error in

```
            let ridesClient = RidesClient()

            let pickupLocation = CLLocation(latitude: 37.787654, longitude: -122.402760)
            let dropoffLocation = CLLocation(latitude: 37.775200, longitude: -122.417587)
            let builder = RideParametersBuilder()
            builder.pickupLocation = pickupLocation
            builder.dropoffLocation = dropoffLocation

            ridesClient.fetchProducts(pickupLocation: pickupLocation) { products, response in
                print(response.response)
                print(products)
                guard let uberX = products.filter({$0.productGroup == .uberX}).first else {
                    // Handle error, UberX does not exist at this location
                    return
                }
                builder.productID = uberX.productID
                ridesClient.fetchRideRequestEstimate(parameters: builder.build(), completion: { rideEstimate, response in
                    guard let rideEstimate = rideEstimate else {
                        // Handle error, unable to get an ride request estimate
                        return
                    }
                    builder.upfrontFare = rideEstimate.fare
                    self.ridesClient.requestRide(parameters: builder.build(), completion: { ride, response in
                        guard let ride = ride else {
                            // Handle error, unable to request ride
                            return
                        }
                        // Ride has been requested!
                    })
                })
            }

            // Completion block. If accessToken is non-nil, you’re good to go
            // Otherwise, error.code corresponds to the RidesAuthenticationErrorType that occured
        })
    } 



   https://api.uber.com/v1.2/products?latitude=37.787654&longitude=-122.40276 } { Status Code: 401, Headers {
        Connection =     (
            "keep-alive"
        );
        "Content-Length" =     (
            63
        );
        "Content-Type" =     (
            "application/json"
        );
        Date =     (
            "Mon, 20 Nov 2017 11:08:29 GMT"
        );
        Server =     (
            nginx
        );
        "Strict-Transport-Security" =     (
            "max-age=604800"
        );
        "X-Content-Type-Options" =     (
            nosniff
        );
        "X-XSS-Protection" =     (
            "1; mode=block"
        );
    } })
```

Comment: Provided location return list of products on sandbox and production environment. Looks like your question is not complete. I don't see what kind of problem you have? Looks like missing info on your question?

Comment: Varun, you may be getting an error with your `.login` call, but you're not checking for it. Can you see what that error is?